# In Meteor, how can I create a single generic event handler that works across all templates?

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events

In the Meteor docs http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps it states "http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps"  and the tutorials show Templates taking events such as with.

```
Template.template1.events = {
  'click #btnSubmit': function (event) {
    //do something
  }
};

Template.template2.events = {
  'click #btnSubmit': function (event) {
    //do something
  }
};
```

I don't want have to create this boilerplate for each of my Meteor Templates that has a submit button.  I would rather have one event handler for all forms and all submit buttons.

How can I have a single click handler? or other event handlers for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you can do is create the function elsewhere and just use it as the callback for each separate template's event:

```js
var clickHandler = function(item) {
    // Do whatever
};

Template.template1.events({
    'click #btnSubmit': clickHandler
});

Template.template2.events({
    'click #btnSubmit': clickHandler
});
```